# How to properly "merge/purge" exported windows event logs?

Tags: windows, events, logging, duplicates

I'm looking for ideas/suggestions on how to improve a process for de-duplicating Windows event log entries in exported .evt files.

We collect exported Windows logs from a number of machines on a daily basis.  These are then transferred to a separate facility for archiving, analysis, etc.  Our process renames each log file with the year and day #, and those are archived.  So for machine "Server1", for example, we will have each day's logs available in files like this:

```
Server1_2016_001_Application.evt
Server1_2016_002_Application.evt
Server1_2016_003_Application.evt
```

...and so on.  We do this for each log type (System, Security, some others as well).

In order to avoid getting lots of duplication, I've been using wevtutil to produce trimmed-down copies of these files like so:

```
wevtutil epl "Application.evt" "Server1_2016_003_Application.evt" "/q:*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z' and @SystemTime<='2016-01-02T23:59:59.999Z']]]" /lf:true /ow:true
```

But this and other attempts I've made are clumsy; "003" export might not have ALL the entries from day 3, as I don't have control over when the logs are exported at the source.  I can instead process just the previous day's entries, but there are times when we want/need to see events right up to the point that the logs were exported.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to determine what the LAST log entry is in a given file, so that for the next day I can query for only events that occur after that entry.  IOW, for each event log type for each machine, I want to capture the time tag, etc. of the last entry and persist that info to disk so that the next day, I can read and use that info as the starting point for that day's processing.